In John 8:59 was picking up stones more of a threat to express their distain or a real danger?
In John 8:59 was picking up stones more of a threat to express their distain or a real danger?

So they picked up stones to throw at him, but Jesus hid himself and went out of the temple.
(John 8:59, ESV)

Kenneth E. Bailey wrote that the Temple area was heavily guarded by Roman solders.

The temple area is about thirty-five acres. At that time, around three sides of that large enclosure there was a long, covered walkway. The best English word we have for this is cloister. Connected to this walkway on the north end of the temple area, Herod the Great had constructed a large military fort. He knew that civil unrest often began in the temple enclosure, so he insured that there was access from the fort both to the temple area and to the roof of this covered walkway. Josephus, a Jewish historian of the first century, records that during feast days Roman soldiers would patrol along that walkway and through the crowds, keeping a sharp eye out for any unrest. He wrote, “a Roman legion went several ways among the cloisters, with their arms, on the Jewish festivals, in order to watch the people, that they might not there attempt to make any innovations.”
--
Bailey, K. E. (2008). Jesus through Middle Eastern Eyes: Cultural Studies in the Gospels (pp. 232–233). IVP Academic.

John 18:31 indicates that the Romans did not allow the Jews use capital punishment.

Pilate said to them, “Take him yourselves and judge him by your own law.” The Jews said to him, “It is not lawful for us to put anyone to death.”
(John 18:31, ESV)

Putting these passages together seems to indicate that Jesus was safer in the Temple than outside the Temple.  Jesus avoided traveling with the people in which the authorities would look to find him, and he avoided the beginning of the feast when they would look for him.  When Jesus started teaching, they challenged Jesus with words, not with stoning or immediate arrest.

My time has not yet come, but your time is always here.  The world cannot hate you, but it hates me because I testify about it that its works are evil.  You go up to the feast. I am not going up to this feast, for my time has not yet fully come.”  After saying this, he remained in Galilee.
(John 7:6–9, ESV)


About the middle of the feast Jesus went up into the temple and began teaching. 15 The Jews therefore marveled, saying, “How is it that this man has learning, when he has never studied?”
(John 7:14–15, ESV)


My information is not worthy of a formal answer; but I have heard that Rome permitted executions within the temple complex.  If this is true, then Jesus faced greater danger within the temple than without.

For this question we need background information, e.g. Kenneth E. Bailey used Josephus. My understanding is the Jews needed permission from Rome.  They did stone Stephen, but not in the Temple area, but that is a different related question.  Were  they violating Roman authority?

@PerryWebb... Although a trial seems to have been involved in Stephen's case, Acts describes a lynching rather than a legal execution after a formal verdict: "When they heard this, they were infuriated, and they ground their teeth at him.... But they cried out in a loud voice, covered their ears,[d] and rushed upon him together. .. 58 They threw him out of the city, and began to stone him.


Acts reports Paul would have been killed had the Romans not intervened. 2. There is archaeological evidence supporting the fact Rome allowed the Jews to kill those who violated Temple prohibitions. This included Roman citizens. You can google the Temple warning inscription. Written in Greek and Latin.


First Century JudaismThe answer is found in the history of Judaism of the first century. Recall that all during this time the Roman government stationed Procurators in Judea because of the many riots and tumult caused by radical---and not so radical---zealots of the Law and Jewish patriots (Pharisees, Sadducees, Herodians, Zealots, etc.) See:

Josephus, History of the Jews
Jewish Encyclopedia
Alfred Edersheim, Life and Times of Jesus the Messiah

That there was physical in-fighting over theology was all too common. That violators of the Law were attacked, and that blasphemers were stoned (killed), and even adulterers condemned, is a matter of history. Recall that Paul had permission from the Elders (Sanhedrin?) to attack Christians; Stephen was stoned; James was killed at the behest of the elders. Much of this was outside the Temple compound, but there were many incidents of rioting within the Temple in spite of the Roman soldiers' presence. Assassins mingled among the crowds during feast days.
So, Jesus's life was indeed in danger, whether inside the Temple...even outside the hometown synagogue of Nazareth...or in the secluded Garden of Gethsemene.  Remember that Jesus spent most of His time up north in Galilee and Perea because it was too dangerous for Him to travel in Judea. (John 7:6-9 e.g.) Note also:

And when the chief priests and Pharisees had heard his parables, they perceived that He spake of them.But when they sought to lay hands on Him, they feared the multitude, because they took Him for a prophet.

