Why did Jesus announce John 7:37 on the last day of The Feast of Tabernacles?

John 7:37-39 NIV
On the last and greatest day of the festival, Jesus stood and said in a loud voice, “Let anyone who is thirsty come to me and drink. [38] Whoever believes in me, as Scripture has said, rivers of living water will flow from within them.” [39] By this he meant the Spirit, whom those who believed in him were later to receive. Up to that time the Spirit had not been given, since Jesus had not yet been glorified.

What is the significance of Jesus making this announcement on the last day of the Feast of Tabernacles?

Although a significantly different question, this question is about the same context as your question: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/96147/in-john-859-was-picking-up-stones-more-of-a-threat-to-express-their-distain-or

According to Adele Reinhartz in The Jewish Annotated New Testament, the last day of the Feast of Tabernacles was marked by a golden pitcher of water being brought from the Pool of Siloam to the Temple. This was done to remind the people of their deliverance from thirst through water flowing from the Rock (Num. 20). It was also a celebration of messianic hope with the final day being known as "The Great Hosannah." From Mishnah Sukkah 4:

With regard to the rite of water libation performed in the Temple
during the Festival, how was it performed? One would fill a golden jug
with a capacity of three log with water from the Siloam pool. When
those who went to bring the water reached the Gate of the Water, so
called because the water for the libation was brought through this
gate leading to the Temple courtyard, they sounded a tekia, sounded a
terua, and sounded another tekia [these are musical patterns on the shofar] as an expression of joy.

It may be notable in this context that John's gospel alone mentions the Pool of Siloam (9:7). In any case, the above practices were apparently known to the author, who presents Jesus as declaring himself to be the true giver of the "water of life" in this context.
Conclusion: Jesus probably announced himself in this manner on the last day of the Feast of Tabernacles because this celebrated the Israelites drinking water from the Rock during their course in the wilderness.

@ DanFefferman - Great answer. This action by Jesus  demonstrated the supernatural foretelling (prophetic) aspect of all the ancient Mosaic feasts and rituals.  And more importantly, it shows how Jesus would expand, enlarge, and empower them in a new dimension in the Messianic era that, by application, would bless people in all the nations. (Recalling Genesis 12'  promises)  This dispensing of the Holy Spirit would make Abraham jump up and rejoice with a chorus of Hallelujahs!

As Dan and Ray have already pointed out, the announcement was made in the context of the Second Temple era celebrations and rituals.
The feast of tabernacles was the most joyful time of all celebrations in the liturgical year of the Old Testament Israelites. For that reason, it was often called in short the feast. It was just after the time of repentance and restoration of the day of atonement. It was also a celebration of the last harvest of the year. The fruit harvest. On top of that, the wet season and the early rains were just behind the corner.
The water libation carried out together with the usual wine/drink offering had a great significance. The Hebrew word for wine (yayin יין) is contained in the word judge (dayan דיין). On the other hand, the word for water (mayim מים) is contained in the word for mercy (rachamim רחמים). Symbolically pouring on the altar water and wine together was a plea for mercy and "watering down" the judgement.
The basis of the ritual was the text of Isaiah 12:

1 In that day you will say: “I will praise you, Lord. Although you
were angry with me, your anger has turned away and you have comforted
me. 2 Surely God is my salvation; I will trust and not be afraid. The
Lord, the Lord himself, is my strength and my defense he has become my
salvation.” 3 With joy you will draw water from the wells of
salvation. 4 In that day you will say: “Give praise to the Lord,
proclaim his name; make known among the nations what he has done, and
proclaim that his name is exalted. 5 Sing to the Lord, for he has done
glorious things; let this be known to all the world. 6 Shout aloud and
sing for joy, people of Zion, for great is the Holy One of Israel
among you.”

The pronunciation of the Hebrew word for salvation (yeshua ישועה) and the Messiah's name (Jesus/Yeshua ישוע) is the same. Although the Hebrew word salvation may have different forms and different pronunciations, Isaiah 12:3 uses ישועה.
On the last day of the feast, Jesus publicly announces that He is the fulfilment of the text serving as the basis of the ritual. He is God standing among His people and the wells of salvation taking away the judgement.

"the significance of Jesus making this announcement on the last day of the Feast of Tabernacles" can depend upon one's denominational view of scripture, so perhaps the question isn't suitable for this site.
But in case it is okay, here is the view from the perspective of a church that believes that God's seven holy days symbolize his plan for mankind.
The Eighth Day: Eternal Life Offered to All, a chapter of the God's Holy Day Plan: The Promise of Hope for All Mankind,
describes this final holy day at the end of the Feast of Tabernacles (also called "The Last Great Day"), and how it symbolizes "The Great White Throne Judgement") at the end of the Millennium (when Jesus "tabernacles" on Earth for a thousand years):

The Eighth Day
Paul tells us that God "desires all men to be saved and to come to the knowledge of the truth" (1 Timothy 2:4).
Peter adds that God is "not willing that any should perish but that all should come to repentance" (2 Peter 3:9).
This is God's overriding goal in dealing with mankind: He desires as many as possible to repent, come to the knowledge of the truth and receive His gift of salvation!
Jesus explained how this will come to pass.
John 7:1-14 describes how Jesus went to Jerusalem for the Feast of Tabernacles.
He appeared publicly and stood in the midst of the people, crying out: "If anyone thirsts, let him come to Me and drink.
He who believes in Me, as the Scripture has said, out of his heart will flow rivers of living water" (John 7:37-38).
…
The theme of Christ's teaching then continues in chapter 8 (which is clearly the next morning, John 8:2) and includes the offer of salvation to all mankind.
In Leviticus 23:39, we see that this day immediately follows the Feast of Tabernacles but is a separate festival with its own distinct meaning.
Based on Christ's words and the theme of offering salvation to all mankind, this festival is sometimes referred to as "the Last Great Day," although the Bible simply calls it "the eighth day."
What was the significance of Christ's teaching about "living water"? In His day, according to tradition, during the Feast of Tabernacles the priests would bring golden vessels of water from the Pool of Siloam on the south side of Jerusalem and pour it over the altar at the temple.
Joyous celebration along with the sounding of trumpets marked this ceremony as the people sang the words of Isaiah, "With joy you will draw water from the wells of salvation" (Isaiah 12:3).
Jesus stood where all could hear Him and drew a lesson from the water, revealing that all who were thirsty could come to Him and be refreshed—forever.
In Christ's analogy, the water represented God's Holy Spirit, which those who believed in Jesus would receive (John 7:39).
He showed that the basic wants of spiritual thirst and hunger could be satisfied only by Him as "the bread of life" (John 6:48) and the source of living water.
…
As Paul further wrote, "And so all Israel will be saved" (Romans 11:26).
This does not mean every last individual, as some will ultimately reject God's offer of salvation ("What Is the Fate of the Unrepentant?").
But clearly the preponderance of the nation will be saved.
Yet not only Israel, but all who have never had a chance to drink from the living waters of God's Word and His Holy Spirit will at last be able to do so (Romans 9:22-26).
God will freely offer them the opportunity for eternal life.
This final period of judgment completes God's plan of salvation for the world.
It will be a time of love, deep mercy and the unsearchable judgment of God.
The opportunity to drink of the life-giving waters of the Holy Spirit will indeed quench the deepest thirsts of men and women.
This time of righteous judgment will bring back to life those long forgotten by humanity, but never forgotten by God.
What is the fate of those who die with no real knowledge of Jesus Christ, the Son of God? What hope is there for the billions who have lived and died without knowledge of God's purpose? The Scriptures show that these are not cut off without hope.
He will bring them back to life and give them their opportunity for eternal life as spirit beings in God's Kingdom.
God will see His plan through and bring many sons to glory (Hebrews 2:10).
His promise to pour out His Spirit on all flesh will find its fullest manifestation.
The thirst-quenching waters of the Holy Spirit will be available to all in the time depicted by the Eighth Day, the last of God's annual festivals.

